# Consistency of $L=HOD^{HOD}\subsetneq HOD \neq V$

Tags: set-theory

Following an exercise (V.2.11) in Kunen, I'm trying to construct a model of $(2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2)^{HOD}$ and $L=(HOD)^{HOD}\subsetneq HOD\subsetneq V$.

He gives the hint to start with $V=L$ in the ground model, and to force so that, if $C_\alpha:=\{n\in\omega: 2^{\aleph_{\alpha+n}}=\aleph_{\alpha+n+1}\}$, then $|\{C_\alpha:\alpha\in On\}|\ge\aleph_2$. This is probably done through some Easton poset $\mathbb{P}(E)$, but the details escape me.

Once that's done, we obviously have that $(2^{\aleph_0}\ge \aleph_2)^{HOD}$ holds in the extension, since $C_\alpha\in HOD$ for every $\alpha$.

Also, while $V\neq HOD$ is probably achieved by an automorphism argument, I'm not sure how I'd go about showing $HOD^{HOD}\subset L$ or $HOD^{HOD}\subset HOD$ in $V[G]$.

Comment: I think that the idea here is to have $V=L$, $V[G]$ such that $\mathrm{HOD}^{V[G]}=L$ and $V[G][H]$ such that $\mathrm{HOD}^{V[G][H]}=V[G]$.